How to organize q points in Matdyn.in file (Quantum Espresso)?
To check phonon dispersion of 'Si', I need to prepare matdyn.in file. I have a question regarding the no. of q points (9 in this case), coordinates of q points and no. of q points between a point and the next point. How do I know these info? Would you please suggest me?I am trying to run the following example problem, but cannot understand the q point section.
matdyn.in
&input
    asr='simple', amass(1)=28.0855,
    flfrc='si.444.fc', fldyn='si.dyn.mat', flfrq='si.freq', fleig='si.dyn.eig', q_in_cryst_coord = .false.
    q_in_band_form = .true.
/
 9
 0         0         0      100
 0.75      0.75      0.0    1
 0.2500    1.0000    0.2500 100
 0.000     1         0.000  100
 0         0         0      100
 0.5000    0.5000    0.5000 100
 0         1         0      100
 0.5000    1.0000    0      100
 0.5000    0.5000    0.5000 100

Here is the si.dyn0 file which includes the list of irreducible q-points. I tried to relate it with the above one, but couldn't.
   4   4   4
   8
   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00
  -0.250000000000000E+00   0.250000000000000E+00  -0.250000000000000E+00
   0.500000000000000E+00  -0.500000000000000E+00   0.500000000000000E+00
   0.000000000000000E+00   0.500000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00
   0.750000000000000E+00  -0.250000000000000E+00   0.750000000000000E+00
   0.500000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.500000000000000E+00
   0.000000000000000E+00  -0.100000000000000E+01   0.000000000000000E+00
  -0.500000000000000E+00  -0.100000000000000E+01   0.000000000000000E+00

I also used SeeK-path (https://www.materialscloud.org/work/tools/seekpath) to understand but couldn't match the format of matdyn.in (q point section)
Reciprocal space and Brillouin-zone information
Reciprocal cell vectors (1/Å)
b   x   y   z
b1  -1.1569197656   1.1569197656    1.1569197656
b2  1.1569197656    -1.1569197656   1.1569197656
b3  1.1569197656    1.1569197656    -1.1569197656
Suggested path

Γ—X—U|K—Γ—L—W—X
High-symmetry points (scaled units)
Label   k1  k2  k3
Γ   0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000
K   0.3750000000    0.3750000000    0.7500000000
L   0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.5000000000
U   0.6250000000    0.2500000000    0.6250000000
W   0.5000000000    0.2500000000    0.7500000000
W2  0.7500000000    0.2500000000    0.5000000000
X   0.5000000000    0.0000000000    0.5000000000
High-symmetry points (1/Å)
Label   kx  ky  kz
Γ   0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000
K   0.8676898242    0.8676898242    0.0000000000
L   0.5784598828    0.5784598828    0.5784598828
U   0.2892299414    1.1569197656    0.2892299414
W   0.5784598828    1.1569197656    0.0000000000
W2  -0.0000000000   1.1569197656    0.5784598828
X   0.0000000000    1.1569197656    0.0000000000

Thanks!
